MyApp hasn't added support for that with Siri
I added a custom intents extension to my project.
All seems to be correctly implemented:

in Targets' Signing & Capabilities Siri appears
in info.plist, NSUserActivityTypes specify the custom intent
in project entitlements, Siri is specified
in intent info.plist's, NSExtensionPrincipalClass specify the intent class


The app asks permission to use Siri - I confirm permission.
The app implements the button "Add to Siri" - I add the shortcut.
If I start the shortcut manually, I'm able to perform all the provided actions.
If I start the the intent selecting the app executable on the simulator, I'm able to perform all the actions using Siri with my voice

But ...

If I start the the intent selecting the app executable on the device, when I call Siri it responds " hasn't added support for that with Siri"
If I try to call directly the shortcut with Siri on the device, Siri responds " hasn't added support for that with Siri"

The problem seems to affect only my new iPhone 15 Pro, with iOS 17.3.1. I installed the app on my iPad with iOS 16.3.1 and it works perfectly! Settings seem to be the same in both devices.
I googled on the Internet, but I'm still not able to understand what is going wrong. There are some settings that I'm forgetting?
